# How to set up haproxy with ssl verify to be optional or none based on request path

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy

In Apache you can define SSLVerifyClient to have a value based on Directory. How can I achieve the same in Haproxy?

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?